# Java Oracle database connection error

Tags: java, oracle, oracle10g

I am new to Java and Oracle. I am trying to make an application that lists serial numbers of a product and when you click on a product's serial number from the list, it shows the  other column informations from the database in a textbox. I have a form named CRUD.I am using Oracle 10g. Code is here:

```
package project1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;


public class CRUD extends javax.swing.JFrame {


      Connection connection = null; 
    public CRUD() {

                 try {
              initComponents();
              String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
              Class.forName(driverName);
              String serverName = "192.168.0.36";
              String portNumber = "1521";
              String sid = "XE";
              String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+serverName+":"+portNumber+":"+sid;
              String userName = "HR";
              String password = "hr";
                     try {
                         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,password);
                     } catch (SQLException ex) {
                         Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                     }
                  try {
         String temp="";
         Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SERI_NO FROM KART");


       while(rs.next()) // dönebildiği süre boyunca
       {
           String s = rs.getString("SERI_NO") ; //kolon isimleri oluşturuldu
           temp+=s+"_";
       }        

       Object [] tem_obj;

       tem_obj=temp.split("_");
       listOgrenciler.setListData(tem_obj);

   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(edit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }

      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(CRUD.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }    


         listOgrenciler.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

           @Override
           public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
               if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                   try {
                     Statement stmtx = connection.createStatement();
                       Object[] sss=listOgrenciler.getSelectedValues();
                     String swhere="" ;
                     for (int i = 0; i < sss.length; i++) {
                           swhere+=sss[i].toString()+",";
                       }
                     swhere=swhere.substring(0,swhere.length()-1);
                     ResultSet rsx = stmtx.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM KART where SERI_NO in ("+swhere+")") ;
                     String temp="";

                          Object [] tem_obj;
                         tem_obj=temp.split("_");
                       String ara="";
                         for (int i = 0; i < tem_obj.length; i++) {
                           ara+=tem_obj[i].toString()+"\n";
                         }
                        texttoarea.setText(ara);

                   } catch (SQLException ex) 
                   {
                       Logger.getLogger(edit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                   }         
               }
           }
       });



    }
```

Errors i get are here:

```
20.Şub.2014 11:22:11 project1.CRUD$1 valueChanged
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SNS080961097": invalid identifier
    .....
    at project1.CRUD$1.valueChanged(CRUD.java:78)
    ......
```

As I said before, I am new to both Java and Oracle. If the errors are so obvious don't laugh:)

Comment: You should print out the generated statement and then show *that* to us. And please include the table definition. But I guess you are enclosing character literals in the `IN` clause in double quotes. In SQL, double quotes (`"`) are used to quote identifiers. Character literals need to be enclosed in single quotes so the value should be `'SNS080961097'` **not** `"SNS080961097"`

Comment: debug to see what your variable `swhere` is carrying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your this query

```
ResultSet rsx = stmtx.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM KART where SERI_NO in ("+swhere+")") ;
```

should be like this:

```
ResultSet rsx = stmtx.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM KART where SERI_NO in ('"+swhere+"')") ;
```

Comment: i marked but i can't vote it up because i am not that popular yet

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problems with you connection step to Oracle DB, its connected successfully, Your problem is within the query. make sure that you have a `SERI_NO` column in your `KART` table.

i suggest you to RUN the both same queries in you code from any `SQL` client such `SQLDeveloper` and see what these queries retrieve.

Comment: The error message is **not** about the `SERI_NO` column.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i don't have a problem with the query it works fine on sqlDeveloper.Code works fine until  listOgrenciler.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() line

Comment: @user3331869 you need to check the both queries because the problem cause by one of them, and i think its the second one.

Answer (score 0):

Observe this statement once,

```
swhere=swhere.substring(0,swhere.length()-1);
```

replace the above statement with the following

```
shere=swhere.substring(0,swhere.length()-2);
```

Because an extra comma(,) is included in your sql statement.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your connection.

Please add some logging to your code and you will know exactly where the error is throwing.

I guess the error is throwing in this line..
SELECT * FROM KART where SERI_NO in ("+swhere+")

You have to specify this as a string with '',where you actual select should look like below.
SELECT * FROM KART where SERI_NO in ('ABC','XCV');

so please check with this one check the value of the "swhere"